# knockoutjs IE 8 : Couldn't find any memo with ID ed2d1f3121ff7e. Perhaps it's already been unmemoized

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, knockout.js

I have a view model coming from the server which I extend with a local java script object. I use

```
viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(serverData); 

$.extend(viewModel, otherItems);
```

the otherItems has additional properties that are marked observable and observableArray. All works well in firefox and chrome but on IE 8 i get

**"Couldn't find any memo with ID ed2d1f3121ff7e. Perhaps it's already been unmemoized "**

on ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

the error goes if I do not extend the object. Any suggestions?

**Edit**
Cannot add full code but here are some snippets

I am using Galleria plugin that reads a div defined in one of my text template. The div is set as below. If I remove this line, I get no errors.

```
<script id="PropertyView" type="text/html">  
...
  <div id="Gallery" data-bind='template: {name:"ImageGallery", foreach: propertyImages}'>

   </div>
```

...

```
    var otherItems = {  
                    similarProperties: ko.observableArray([]),
                    visibleFeatures: ko.observableArray([]), 
                    propertyImages: ko.observableArray([]),
                    currentImageUrl: ko.observable(""),
                    currentImageIndex: ko.observable(-1),
                    previousImage : function()
                    {
                        this.currentImageIndex(this.currentImageIndex() - 1);
                    },
                    nextImage : function()
                    {
                        this.currentImageIndex(this.currentImageIndex() + 1);
                    }
                }

                var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data)

                $.extend(viewModel,otherItems);
                ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: Can you share more code or a jsFiddle?

Comment: Could you investigate the stack trace at the error to see what functions are being called that produce this error?

Comment: @RPNiemeyer added some more code

Answer (score 0):

I also had same issue. Finally i have fixed, template binding causes the issue.   Check your binding elements in your Template which uses the Array you are passing.